# Run node as a service with pm2

Tags: node.js, cmd, pm2

I am trying to run a node api as a service but when I run the following command

```
C:\Windows\System32>pm2-service-install -n 0PM2
```

it asks the following question

```
Perform environment setup (recommended)?
```

I put yes but it stays there and does nothing

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply install the `pm2` package.

```
npm install pm2 -g
```

Run the module that has your server

```
 pm2 start app.js
```

If the above things are working fine, it shows your installation and configuration are correct. Now, use `pm2` commands:

```
pm2 startup
```

follow the command from the o/p of above command

```
pm2 save
```

It seems you are using windows, you should use these steps:

1. download the `pm2-installer` from [here](https://github.com/jessety/pm2-installer).
2. Copy the entire pm2-installer directory onto the target machine, then run:

```
npm run setup
```

3. On Windows, the setup script assumes you have already configured npm to use prefix and cache directories in a location accessible to the Local Service user. If not, it will issue a warning and ask if you're sure you'd like to proceed. To set up npm automatically, run configure first:

```
npm run configure
npm run setup
```

Check [here](https://github.com/jessety/pm2-installer) for more details.